# How to get the activity or application context in AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, unit-testing

I am writing some test case with AndroidTestCase. I want call getCacheDir to get the directory.

```
/data/data/com.mypackage/cache
```

But I have not start up the activity or application. it there any way I can get the activity or application context in AndroidTestCase.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply override getContext() in you subclass of AndroidTestCase

Answer (score 0):

Since you are extending the AndroidTestCase, you can just use the call getContext() to retrieve the context. AndroidTestCase implements it for you.